# 29er Road Tire?

Tags: tire, 29er

Can't find too much info on Google regarding this but anywhere in the UK stock an equivalent 29er road tire or maybe a compromise between off road and on road without too much drag.

Loving the 29er for all journeys on and off road but plan on doing Brighton run in September and ideally would prefer a better road tire.

56 miles on Slant Six tires I'm not looking forward to :)

Comment: 29er is American for a ETRTO 622 rim/tyre, also known as 28" or 700C.

Comment: The fact this question exists says the problem is the slant six being a pretty rubbish tyre.  When you ride a fast XC tyre you don't mind it on the road at all.
In fact a good XC tyre often has less rolling resistance than an average slick touring tyre.

Comment: I wouldn't say the Slant Six is rubbish, it handles well on loose surfaces, bogs up pretty quick in mud though.

Comment: You may have luck looking for 'slick' or 'road' MTB tires. Also 'gravel' type road bikes  use semi off-road tires in width up to about 45mm which you can use.

Comment: 29er is slang for tire whose rim is smaller than a 27" tire.

Answer (score 6):

A 29er MTB tyre and a typical road tyre share the same rim diameter, which is 622mm. So you want a tyre of your desired width and tread with 622 in the ETRTO code.

Check out the internal width of your rims, they will have an ETRTO code of their own printed somewhere like 29-622, and you want to make sure the tyre is wide enough to suit the rim. I.e., a 23 mm road tyre would be too skinny to stay safely on a typical MTB rim. You’ll find advice in safely matching tyre width by googling around or searching this site.

You might see road tyres labelled as a ‘700’ which is an old notation for the same thing. I.e., a 700x38 would be 38-622 in ETRTO.

Comment: Thanks Swifty, I was looking at 700 tires, just couldn't find one close to 52mm.

Comment: @DanK yeah sorry I knew there was a risk I was telling you nothing you didn’t already know.

Answer (score 6):

To find fast rolling tyres have a look at [rolling resistance charts](https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com). Also bear in mind that narrow tyres are not necessarily faster, [summarised by Jan Heine](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2018/01/03/12-myths-in-cycling-1-wider-tires-are-slower/).

MTB 29er tyres and rims have a bead diametre of 622 mm. Such tyres are designated ISO or ETRTO *x* -622, where *x* is the tyre width in millimetres. Some stores list such tyres by their old French designation 700C.

The tyres need to be wide enough to be held securely by your rim. A good guideline is again a European norm. It is described rather well in an [article by Mavic](https://engineerstalk.mavic.com/en/the-right-tyre-width-on-the-right-rim-width/). Find your rim's internal width and compare the list to find which tyres you may ship. Ignore anything in the article about aerodynamics.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure my tires have 700 X 55 maybe 52, will look closer when I get in

Comment: @Dan K Try to find out the inner width of your rims. You may find it in a data sheet, measure it directly after removing the tyres, or estimating it by measuring the outer width and subtracting 4 or 5 mm.

Comment: I've found the tech specs from Kenda for my current tires. Front = 54 X 622 / Back = 50 X 622

Answer (score -2):

I would recomend you **Schwalbe Hurricane** tires. They are noisless and have pretty nice rolling speed. I have been using them for a while, and they serve me excelent for 50 km runs. They are also good for off road if it occours.
So they are good allround tires.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll do some more research when I get in from work.

Comment: Remember that specific product recommendations are off-topic. They're largely a matter of opinion, they go out of date quickly and they can be very regionally specific.

Comment: With the increasing number of 'gravel bikes' around, it might become easier to find a bigger tyre with low rolling resistance.

Comment: Specific product rec is not a good idea for a long-term useful answer.  Instead, try rephrasing your answer to describe the features of a tyre that would help. like "smooth lug-free centerline to help with on-road" and "shoulder lugs for grip when off-road" but also point out the downsides, like "weird squirm effect when taking a road corner fast and leaning enough to put the lugs on the hard surface"

Comment: @DavidRicherby I guess, we also don't want to become a playground for advertisers and influencers... If big companies started paying people for posting ads on SO, the site would be dead in a year.